# Radial wavefunction at origin for excited states $|{R_{nl}}^2| (0)$ for quarkonium

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematica

I am solving the radial Schrodinger wave equation for quarkonium containing a quark and antiquark. The system is non-relativistic as quarks are charm and bottom which are heavy. The wave equation is numerically solved using the R K method in mathematica. I have wavefunction in numerical form.
I want to find the radial wavefunctions for excited orbital angular momentums $|{R_{nl}}^2| (0)$ at the origin.
I know the form given in eq 4.22 by [Quigg and Rosner](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157379900954), but I am not fully confident on how to use this equation. I have calculated the masses already.

Comment: Since you've described your problem all in physics terminology instead of math terminology. I strongly suggest asking the question in a physics forum instead of a math forum. And by the way, don't rely on information behind a paywall to support your question. Nobody is going to be willing to pay their own money to find out what you are talking about.